# Ninject Extension Factory - System.InvalidProgramException - JIT Compiler Encountered an internal limitation

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, jit

After some time of using Ninject without a problem I ran into strange problem with the library Ninject.Extensions.Factory.

My code was compiling and run fine without any of above mention errors.

What's more even if I reverse into revision which was checked and worked perfectly fine the same error occurs.

The problem is that now when calling some of my:

```
IFactory.GetSomeFactory();
```

The Following exception is rising:

```
Message : JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
Source: Ninject.Extensions.Factory
StackTrace:(only top of the stack)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Factory.Factory.InstanceResolver.Get(Type type, String name, Func`2 constraint, IConstructorArgument[] constructorArguments, Boolean fallback)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Factory.StandardInstanceProvider.GetInstance(IInstanceResolver instanceResolver, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] arguments)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Factory.FactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
```

I tried to clear cache of nuget and re-download the libraries but that doesn't help.

Maybe any of You run into similar problem and have some out of the box solution ?

Thanks in Advance for any helps and tips how to solve the Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try turning off IntelliTrace as there's a "known issue" where IntelliTrace can cause this problem, also see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872506/jit-compiler-encountered-an-internal-limitation

```
Tools --> Options --> IntelliTrace --> [ ] Enable IntelliTrace
```

Instead of turning it off completely, it may be enough to set IntelliSense settings to "Show Events Only".

Comment: That helps, although seems to be strange for my anyway.